# How to delete specific remote notification if app is closed or in background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, chat

My app has a chat service, when new notification is received, I want to clear the notifications between user1 and user2 except the new one.

I can do it when app is in foreground by calling:

```
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
        print("count: \(notifications.count)")
        for notif in notifications {
            let nUserInfo = notif.request.content.userInfo
            let nType = Int(nUserInfo[AnyHashable("type")] as! String)
            if nType == type {
                let notifId = notif.request.identifier
                if notifId != notification.request.identifier {
                    center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [notif.request.identifier])
                }
            }
        }
```

where type is a customValue.
How to do this when app is in background or closed by a user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on Background Modes capability and check Remote notifications mode. In order to delete the notification in background, you need to send a new notification with no alert, like `{"aps": {"content-available": 1}, "del-id": "1234"}`, where `content-available` means (you can check more about here [Apple push service](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1))

> Include this key with a value of 1 to configure a background update notification. When this key is present, the system wakes up your app in the background and delivers the notification to its app delegate. For information about configuring and handling background update notifications, see Configuring a Background Update Notification.

and del-id will be the id of the notification you want to delete, you can use an array as well. You can put these information with together with your message notification as well.

In your `AppDelegate.swift` you will need to add this method to delete the notification in background. In your case, you can send the id of the notification you does not want to delete and use your method to delete all delivered notification except the one with the id you send in your last notification.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    guard let idToDelete = userInfo["del-id"] as? String else {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
    }

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [idToDelete])
    completionHandler(.noData)
}
```

Comment: will this run if the app is terminated by user?

Comment: yes, if you use `content-available` in your notifications, it will trigger the delegate of your app.

Comment: Have you tested it? For me it doesn't work. I can successfully update the app badge, but I cannot remove the delivered notifications. I suppose the problem is that the `removeDeliveredNotifications` method executes asynchronously. Any idea on how to solve the issue?